# Tech Spec Template

Tags: design-patterns, design, documentation, architecture

Need to create a tech spec document for a project I am working on that makes some web service calls to a VF page.  I have a few templates for generic Software development Tech Spec documents, but was hoping someone could share either some example documents that are for SF projects or a template of one they prefer to use.

I suppose the generic software development tech spec doc would work, but didn't know if the community could guide me to certain caveats for these documents when working with SF.  Just want to make sure I am using the right sections for the document.  For example, in the past I have used something similar to this as a general outline for a tech Spec

- Revision History
- Purpose of Document
- Workflow
- Architechture
- Use Case Stories

Please offer any advice or share examples if you would.  Really just trying to get a hand getting me started, Not looking for anyone to write it for me, just hoping to make sure I am using the correct outline, and I can go from there.  An example document would be great, but any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Do you have specific concerns about how to document something in Salesforce or just looking for "gotchas" that others wish they had documented?

Comment: Very vague. Probably best to withdraw the question or to frame it around specific uses for Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad and probably too vague for a community helping each other with use of Salesforce. I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Making web service calls to VF pages doesn't make sense to me- perhaps someone else can teach me what that means- unless you mean to expose a web service endpoint using a custom API or a Force.com Site.

Are you asking how to make a tech spec template? OR how to do something specific using Salesforce/Force.com?